# Почему в visual studio не создаётся массив с желаемым кол-вом элементов

Tags: c, массивы

Хочу чтобы массив заполнялся полностью пользователем(размер , элементы) . Пытаюсь просто создать массив arr[n],а visual studio пишет что кол-во должно быть константой . Делал так в Kdevelop на линуксе , работало . Может надо подключить какие-то директивы?

```
int main(void)
{
int n;
printf("Введите кол-во элементов массива: ");
scanf("%d", &n);
float arr[n];



}
```

Comment: http://cppstudio.com/post/9088/

Comment: Просто эта возможность C99 - VLA - в Visual Studio не реализована.

Answer (score 0):

Иван, память под **статический** массив нужного размера, который ввел пользователь не может быть выделена во время выполнения программы. Если же вы хотите использовать массив, размер которого указал сам пользователь, то Вам необходимо динамическое выделение памяти т.е использовать **динамический массив**.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>



int main()
{
    // Установка русской кодировки
    system("chcp 1251");
    system("cls");

    int* arr    = NULL;
    int sizeArr = 0;

    printf("Введите резмер массива: ");
    scanf_s("%d", &sizeArr);

    // Если введенный размер > 0, то запрашиваем нужное количество памяти
    if (sizeArr > 0)
    {
        arr = (int*)malloc(sizeArr * sizeof(int));
    }

    // Проверяем arr на наличие пустого (нулевого) указателя (NULL)
    if (arr != NULL)
    {
        printf("Заполните массив.\n");

        // Заполняем массив
        for (int i = 0; i < sizeArr; ++i)
        {
            printf("arr[%d] = ", i);
            scanf_s("%d", &arr[i]);
        }

        printf("Массив: ");

        // Вывод массива в консоль
        for (int i = 0; i < sizeArr; ++i)
        {
            printf("%d ", arr[i]);
        }

        printf("\n");

        // Очищаем ранее выделенную память
        free(arr);
        arr = NULL;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

> Функция *malloc* **выделяет** необходимое количество байтов памяти и возвращает указатель на неё. *malloc* возвращает указатель типа void, поэтому его нужно **самостоятельно** приводить к нужному типу использовав явное приведение типов.
> Если же вам все же нужен статический массив, то воспользуйтесь директивой препроцессора #define [Текст] [Замена]. [Более подробную информацию Вы найдете здесь](https://habr.com/ru/post/546946/)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


#define MAX_SIZE 100


int main()
{
    // Установка русской кодировки
    system("chcp 1251");
    system("cls");

    int arr[MAX_SIZE];
    int sizeArr = 0;


    printf("Введите резмер массива: ");
    scanf_s("%d", &sizeArr);


    printf("Заполните массив.\n");

    for (int i = 0; i < sizeArr; ++i)
    {
        printf("arr[%d] = ", i);
        scanf_s("%d", &arr[i]);
    }

    printf("Массив: ");

    for (int i = 0; i < sizeArr; ++i)
    {
        printf("%d ", arr[i]);
    }

    printf("\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Вы сильно удивитесь, но когда в коде написано `int main(){int a[10];...}`, то память выделяется на самом деле во время выполнения (там просто указатель стека чуточку (на 40 байт) сдвигается, но все же). А при компиляции память выделится как бы не может.

Comment: Спасибо большое за помощь и за объяснения

Comment: Только у меня вопрос , а почему KDE на линуксе пропускала это?

Comment: потому что в "KDE на Linux" используется gcc, а gcc умеет в VLA.